# Row level Formula: Field reference via Lookup

Tags: reporting

Is there any chance to use a row level Formula column on reports which copies a value that is stored on another object?
Both objects are related via lookup.

Comment: You can create custom report types to get the lookup fields on the report, there is no need to use row level formulas here

Comment: Hey @sumitbhatt , thanks for your answer. I know that there is in option to "add fields via lookup" using a Cusotm Report Type. However, the Lookup field I have is a Lookup(User, Group) field. It does not show me all fields stored on the User Object once I would want to add the desired field via Lookup. Thats why I now created a field on the Object2 with this formula "Owner: User.DesiredField__c 
But this solution is not desired since I would rather like to make use of the row level formula column and not create an extra field on Object2.

Comment: Row level formulas can only use the fields that are available in the report, so you will not be able to use lookup fields in report unless you add that field in report, also to add to your last comment you can access all the fields custom as well as standard from owner lookup in a custom report type

Comment: Hey @sumit thank you very much. That makes sense. So row level formula would not work in this case. Could you please explain the last part of your answer? I now that it usually work to add fields via lookup on a custom report type. But I have found a difference between Lookup(User) and Lookup(User, Group). In my case I have a Lookup(User, Group). Whenever I click on "add fields via lookup" for Lookup(User), I can add all fields from the user object, also the custom created fields. This is however not the case for the Lookup(User, Group) fields. Then I can only add a few fields from the user

Comment: object. Do you know if there is a way to handle with such cases to add them on a custom report type? Thanks in advance